# R getting rid of single quote character

Tags: regex, r, encoding, utf

I have a vector of character strings I'm trying to process, but I can't get rid of some weird characters.

When I read the csv file I used the following line:

```
train <- read.csv(file="files/file1.csv", header = T, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

I used this line to try and get rid of punctuation:

```
train$var1 <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", " ", train$var1)
```

However on inspection after running it, I'm still seeing weird single quotes, '...', and black dots like a password cloaking character.  Here's the dput:

```
dput(unique(unlist(var1List))[c(30242:30246, 30561, 30484)])
c("opportunity…", "about…", "expected…", "reward…", "us…", "‘as", 
"<U+25CF>")
```

Any suggestions for getting rid of these characters?

Comment: How about removing everything except a "whitelist" of allowed characters? Can you define such a whitelist?

Comment: that tick in `as` is an accent rather than a quote.  You also have the ellipses character rather than three periods.  `gsub('[^A-z0-9]', '', x)` will keep only letters and numbers but you loose the unicode representation in the last string.

Comment: @Justin: Don't use `[A-z]`. It matches more than just letters. (Also, that's not an accent, it's a (single curly) quote).

Comment: @TimPietzcker Oh! what else does it match?

Comment: @Justin: It also matches square brackets, backslash, caret, underscore and backtick (just look at an ASCII character map).

Comment: @Justin Probably safer to use something like `[:alnum:]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could remove everything except a set of legal characters:

```
train$var1 <- gsub("[^\\w\\s]", " ", train$var1, perl = TRUE)
```

would change every character that's not an alphanumeric or a whitespace character into a space, for example.

Comment: I don't think that this is a valid R regex. '\w' is an unrecognized. (even with grep=T)

Comment: @joran: Thanks, I keep forgetting the double backslashes - but is `perl = TRUE` really necessary?

Comment: Well, I'm not a regex expert, I'm just testing on the OP's example vector, and without `perl = TRUE` almost everything is exchanged for empty spaces.

Comment: @joran -- Interesting. It does look like R's native regex engine doesn't handle the *shorthand* character classes (`\\w`, `\\s`, etc) inside of `[]`. (It interprets them as `\ ` and `w` or `\ ` and `s`). The *longer* versions do work without `perl=TRUE`, as shown by running `gsub("[^[:alnum:][:space:]]", " ", train$var1)`